# Bash script not checking for null correctly

Tags: bash, jq

I have a bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

someId=$(curl -sk -H -X POST -d "fizzbuzz" "https://someapi.example.com/v1/orders/fire" | jq '.someId')

if [ -z "$someId" ]; then
  echo "Order Placement failed; unable to parse someId from the response"
  exit 1
fi

echo "...order $someId placed"
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
...order null placed
```

So somehow `$someId` is `null` but then...shouldn't I be seeing the `"Order Placement failed; unable to parse someId from the response"` echo instead?

**How can I modify the `if [ -z "$someId" ]; then` conditional to execute if `$someId` is null?**

Comment: the string "null" is not zero-length, it's four bytes. `-z` checks only for zero-length strings.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is more like `[ -z "$someId" ] || [ "$someId" = null ]` (splitting it into two separate tests that way complies with current POSIX guidelines; see the OB markers in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, flagging other ways to combine tests as obsolescent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "null string" is an empty string -- a zero-byte string, that is, a string with no characters contained within it. `s=""` assigns a null string to the variable `s`, just as `s=` or `s=''` do.

`s=null`, or `s='null'`, or `s="null"`, by contrast, assign a string with the four-byte string `null` (and then terminated by a literal NUL character, as all C strings are). These strings are not "null strings" or "empty strings" in the sense that `test -z "$s"` or `[ -z "$s" ]` check for: It doesn't have zero characters; instead, it has four (those being `n`, `u`, `l` and `l`).

To detect *either* an empty string or the non-empty string `"null"`, use instead:

```
if [ -z "$someId" ] || [ "$someId" = null ]; then
  echo "Order Placement failed; unable to parse someId from the response"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `--exit-status` option, which makes `jq` have a non-zero exit status if the last output value is `false` or `null`.

```
#! /bin/bash


if ! someId=$(curl -sk -H -X POST -d "fizzbuzz" "https://someapi.example.com/v1/orders/fire" | jq -r --exit-status '.someId'); then
  echo "Order Placement failed; unable to parse someId from the response"
  exit 1
fi

echo "...order $someId placed"
```

Comment: Should that be `if ! someId=...`?

Comment: Also `jq -j` or `jq -r` would be more appropriate to transmit the `someId` content, or the value returned is of the JSON format that is not appropriate in most cases for shell, like a null in JSON is the `null` keyword.